# If statements and blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that references a few other sheets and does a couple of calculations that I need some support with.

I need in simple terms to complete the following calculation:

```
if (sales-cost)/sales > 0.25, sales, cost/0.74
```

but also need if cost is blank then `"POA"`

Effectively if we already make north of `25%` the sales rate stays, if its less than `25%` it needs uplifting to `26%`

I've used an if to cover off the blank and the `26%` margin, just not the validation on current margin

Comment: Sounds like a simple enough `IF()` statement, perhaps nested.  What have you tried? Please show your current formula attempts, and any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

So like this:

```
=if(A1="","POA",if((B1-A1)/B1>=0.25,B1,A1/0.74))
```

Assuming cost is in cell A1 and sales in cell B1